# CakePHP 3: Plugin routing without a slash at the end?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

Admin plugin / PagesController methods:

- home
- index
- add
- ..

removed default display method.

Problem, i can't access url without slash at end **mysite.com/admin/pages** , if i try get redirect to **mysite.com/admin/webroot/pages** and error message

**Error: WebrootController could not be found.**

For all other Controllers url without slash at end works.

Router in admin plugin / config:

```
Router::plugin('Admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/new-password', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'newPassword']);
    $routes->connect('/reset-password', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'resetPassword']);
    //$routes->connect('/pages', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

Comment: Do you by chance have folder named "page" in your webroot directory?

Comment: No, only standard folders

Comment: Sounds like a web server configuration issue to me. Such as in Apache it thinks that without a -d or -f switch it's a file or folder.

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` to your `webroot/.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread on github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6279) may help you.

For what I know, the only way is to set the document root to /webroot

For anyone interested on changing the document root for the primary domain on cPanel: [check here](https://www.servint.net/university/article/the-tech-bench-changing-a-document-root-in-cpanel/)